# Git "fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository"

Tags: cron, git

```
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
```

I'm trying to cron some git commands under the user `www-data` and it doesn't work.

To troubleshoot, I tried to run `sudo -u www-data git show` but it returns `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository`

If I run `sudo -u www-data git diff --shortstat` it returns `warning: Not a git repository. Use --no-index to compare two paths outside a working tree`

I also tried adding into `sudoers`

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git show

# and also

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

Still getting the same errors. Any ideas why? Thank you.

Comment: We don’t have enough information to help you. Are you in the git repo directory when you run these commands? Is there a `.git` directory? Does the repo directory belong to `www-data`?

Comment: yes, `.git` exists and i'm in a git repo. I came to realize that git requires the current user to be the owner of the files, it doesn't work if current user is a "member" of the `www-data` group

Comment: You could `git config --global --add safe.directory <the path>` with your current user which should be fine for read-only commands like `git status`, but I’m not sure of the implications of pushing/pulling with a different user than the one owning the repo ([see the docs of this config here](https://fossies.org/linux/git/Documentation/config/safe.txt)).

Comment: I did try `safe.directory` but still gave me the same error and yes I'm reading only.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor/76406879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git requires the current user to be the owner of the files, it does not work if current user is a "member" of the group

For `.git` files belonging to `user1:group1`

- Git will not throw error if you are `user1`
- Git will throw error if you are `user2:group1`

### Solution 1 (Best)

Since this is automated/cron, it is easier to just prefix the user to run as. Specify the user before the git command

`sudo -u <user> git ...`

### Solution 2

Slighting more cumbersome as you need to add every repository to the `user`'s `.gitconfig` and there is a very detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100228/3872647

```
[safe]
    directory = <real path of git repository, symlink won't work here>
```

I hope this is clear enough, otherwise please ask or comment and I will modify this answer.

Comment: Maybe not a complete answer? Didn't work for me.

Comment: do you have the same error? who is the `owner:group` of the `.git` folder and files? which user is running the git commands?

Comment: I was getting "fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository". I used the "safe.directory" approach so I could again run commands. I committed all my changes, pushed to a remote, erased the working directory, and built it new via clone from the remote. The message went away for me, but now that I'm thinking about it, I checked and the "dubious" message is back. Sigh. I read that Git tolerates either "root" or <user>. Right now I have "root:<user>". It's late here; I'll try tomorrow. Maybe it must be either "root:root" or "<user>:<user>".

Comment: Since `.git` and insides are owned by `root`, then `root` must be running the commands. If you run the commands as `<user>` (not `root`), it will show the error.

Comment: I used all six commands at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209644; it worked. Maybe Git wants quite a number of permissions to have specific values!

Answer (score 1):

+1 for "git requires the current user to be the owner of the files"

- my current git version is 2.43.1 and this error message is new as of ?.?.?
- setting safe.directories did nothing
- a script I'm using starts with `sudo -u www-data bash -c '...'` and I found that indeed at least .git and children need to be owned by `www-data`

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that if you edit the .gitconfig file in your user folder (should be something like `/home/your_user/.gitconfig`) and insert:

`[safe]
directory = /path/to/directory`
the `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository` error would not appear anymore.

Comment: thanks, i have added it to my answer, your method will be helpful for those who are typing commands on the CLI